# get excel sheet column names using exceldatareader

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I'm writing the C# library to read the Excel Files without any other dependencies like OLDEB(AccessDatabaseEngine) library.

So I have chosen the ExcelDataReader Library for Reading the .XLS and .XLSX files.

ExcelDataReader is perfectly working with both file formats with my local and deployment server environment.

I'm facing issue, how to get all the columns names from given Excel files?

Comment: What do you mean with column names? Like A, B, C as shown in Excel or?

Comment: @venkat: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The same answer of @Kevin, but need to set ExcelDataReader to use header row as column titles.
the code will look like the following:

```
var stream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\Book1.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() {
ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() {
    UseHeaderRow = true
}
});

var tables = result.Tables
                   .Cast<DataTable>()
                   .Select(t => new {
                                     TableName = t.TableName,
                                     Columns = t.Columns
                                                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                                .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                                .ToList()
                          });
```

Comment: If you use  CreateReader(stream) instead  CreateOpenXmlReader(stream), you will get better compatibility with the different Excel formats. By using it, you are letting the ExcelReaderFactory object select the proper underneath method (either CreateOpenXmlReader or CreateBinaryReader).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to cast both the `DataTableCollection` and `DataColumnCollection` so you can use normal Linq queries over them.

For example:

```
var stream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\Book1.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

var result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

var tables = result.Tables
                   .Cast<DataTable>()
                   .Select(t => new {
                                     TableName = t.TableName,
                                     Columns = t.Columns
                                                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                                .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                                .ToList()
                          });
```

The reason the cast is necessary is because both `DataTableCollection` and `DataColumnCollection` only implement `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>` as they date back to the days before generics.

For this code to work your spreadsheet has to actually contain defined tables not just have data in it.